# DotNetZip Extracting file causes "Overflow while creating filename" error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dotnetzip

Having a weird issue with using DotNetZip where, when trying to read a zip file, I get the error

> Ionic.Zip.ZipException: Cannot read that as a ZipFile ---> System.OverflowException: overflow while creating filename

The code I am using is

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file.FullName))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(extractedFolder, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

I originally assumed this was an error with the filename, however it is not a long file name/path, well under the 260 character limit imposed by windows, and other files with the same length have been extracted without issues.

Comment: The best way to get the answer is to ask the creator. Just make a sample project that will cause the error as you mention here and open an issue, upload it at here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic . that would receive best support for this issue.